# Kafka topic is still associating with old consumer group of Kafka Streams application

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I have a stream join application where I have joined two KStreams (say reading from `topic1`, `topic2`) using a group id say consumergroup1. later I have changed one topic from `topic2` to `topic3`. Now under the consumergroup1 I still see three topics (`topic1`, `topic2` and `topic3` ) and I see lag on `topic2` (which I am no longer using in the stream join and some other process is producing messages on this topic)

can someone suggest what is the best way to get rid of the unused topic(say `topic2` in above example) from the consumergroup1.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Streams applications are stateful, they "remember stuff" across restarts to be able to resume computation where they left off as well as to continue reading from Kafka from the last committed offset.

In a development environment, you're probably safe just deleting that state when you want, which by default is stored in `/var/lib/kafka-streams/<application.id>`, or to use the application reset tool (see https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html#step-2-reset-the-local-environments-of-your-application-instances).

You can also just use a different [application.id](https://kafka.apache.org/27/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#application-id) across restarts.

In a production environment, what to do in that case is more ad-hoc since there's data in those topic and you typically want to do something with it => you typically code a bit around that case to make sure the transition from `topic2` to `topic3` is doing exactly what you want. Maybe for example you just leave `topic2` lying around and you just never push any new data to it, s.t. the lag stays at 0.